# Select status from a column to populate another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which is daily updated with a list of companies at different states of bankruptcy (`**text**`). These status can vary and new ones can be added.

What the macro has to do is fill the `column A` with the current bankruptcy status of the company, and delete it from `column B`. An example, before:

```
column A    column B
            **Bankruptcy Required**
            Company 1
            Company 2
            Company 3
            **Bankruptcy Decreed**
            Company 4
            Company 5
            **Extinct Bankruptcy Process**
            Company 6
            **Required Reorganization**
            Company 9
            Company 10
            Company 11
            **Judicial Recovery Upheld**
            Company 12
            Company 14
            Company 15
            Company 16
```

After:

```
column A                          column B
Bankruptcy Required               Company 1
Bankruptcy Required               Company 2
Bankruptcy Required               Company 3
Bankruptcy Decreed                Company 4
Bankruptcy Decreed                Company 5
Extinct Bankruptcy Process        Company 6
Required Reorganization           Company 9
Required Reorganization           Company 10
Required Reorganization           Company 11
Judicial Recovery Upheld          Company 12
Judicial Recovery Upheld          Company 14
Judicial Recovery Upheld          Company 15
Judicial Recovery Upheld          Company 16
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your document, will it literally say `**Bankruptcy Required**` and the like? Or is there a technical marker that notes that?  The thought is to go through each cell in column B, when it finds some text (`**Bankruptcy` or `**Judicial`), place that in column A, and copy all the cells below, until the next "bankruptcy" part and repeat.  Edit: This can also probably be done with a formula, given the different types of "Column A" parts.  Have you tried anything? If so, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the rows and examine what is in Column B.

```
Private Sub FixData()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim szStatus As String
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = 1

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through the rows
    Do While lrow <= lastRow
        'Check if the value in column B is bold
        If ws.Range("B" & lrow).Font.Bold = True Then
            'Get the value
            szStatus = Trim(ws.Range("B" & lrow).Value)
            'Delete that row
            ws.Rows(lrow).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            'If it does not have ** in it we get to here
            If ws.Range("B" & lrow).Value <> "" Then
                'Write the status we got from the line we deleted into column A.
                ws.Range("A" & lrow).Value = szStatus
            End If
            lrow = lrow + 1
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Close @MatthewD ! But the ** just indicates that the text in that line is bold. The character * is not present there. Any idea how to do the same that you did checking for bold text' lines?

Comment: Sure @AYJK I believe that it is Range().Font.Bold = True. I'll make the change to the answer so you can try it but I can't test it myself until tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much @MatthewD ! It works just perfect. Is there any "thumbs up" that I can do for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Possible without VBA, for example by adding an extra column:

[image: SO33508293 example]

The formula in A2 being:

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH("Bankruptcy",C2),IFERROR(SEARCH("Required",C2),IFERROR(SEARCH("Judicial",C2),)))
```

and in B2:

```
=IF(A2>0,C2,B1)
```

If the formula are converted to the values resulting from the formulae then the rows that don't start `0` may be deleted and then the helper column (`A`) also.

Comment: As I said, "These status can vary and new ones can be added", so it should be flexible, I mean, not limited to "bankruptcy", "required" and "judicial".

Comment: Thank you for your response pnuts. Maybe I was kind rude because of my bad english, but I didn't mean it. I agree with you, but I'm really new in VBA and my codes for know are unpublishable!

Comment: Totally agree! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try again then, still without VBA. Define a Name, say BOLD, as:

```
=GET.CELL(20,OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC2",FALSE),0,1))
```

then enter in A2 (of added column, as my other answer):

```
=BOLD
```

and change B2 formula to:

```
  =IF(A2,C2,B1)
```

then proceed as before though delete the `TRUE` rows rather than the non `0` ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

```
Sub CleanAndTransfer2()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim bankruptcy  As String
    ws.Activate
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2))
        If Cells(i, 2).Font.Bold = True Then
            bankruptcy = Cells(i, 2)
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        Cells(i, 1) = bankruptcy
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```